# WatchKit app submission

Tags: ios, store, provisioning-profile, watchkit

I have created an app with `WatchKit`. I have tried with three different bundle identifier:

1. `com.xyz.myappname`
2. `com.xyz.myappname.extension`
3. `com.xyz.myappname.extensionapp`

If I set this and try to validate my app I am getting extension app and `WatchKit` app bundle identifier does not match.

If I keep same bundle identifier for both app then I am getting `CFBundle` identifier collision. Error as follows

> CFBundleidentifier collision : There more than bundle with the                   CFBundleidentifier value `com.xyz.myappname.extension` under the IOS application `myappname.app`

Please let me know whats going wrong and how to set this to publish on AppStore

Comment: Can you set up a demo project, upload it to github and post it here? The first version works exactly fine for me. But please be sure to have all the signing right! There has to be an own App Id for the Extension with all the neccessary Provisioning Profiles etc.!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply
i am also quiet sure i have set  all the signing right, i want to know the way i have created the bndle id is that right?
How many buidle identifier we need thee or two.

Comment: I have three. One for my main app, one for the Watch Extension, one for the Watch App.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem today!

Select your main App target, and go to Build Phases. Under "Copy Bundle Resources", I had to remove the "APPNAME Watchkit App.app".

After that, I was able to submit my App to the App Store.