# Archive validation failed with following error to my Apple watch application

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode-6.2

I wants to upload my Apple Watch application on iTunes. When I am validating my Archive it is giving following error.[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29445082/watchkit-app-submission

Comment: Hi , I already followed that stuff , still facing same issue.

Comment: • In order for Watch apps to function properly, certain properties must match across the Watch app and its App Extension (18857540):

• The WKAppBundleIdentifier property of NSExtensionAttributes in the WatchKit App Extension’s Info.plist must match the CFBundleIdentifier of WatchKit App's Info.plist.

• The WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier property of the WatchKit App's Info.plist must match the CFBundleIdentifier of the Containing iOS App's Info.plist. It seems to be a problem related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608264/error-itms-90451-cfbundleidentifier-collision-error